# Is this a proper operation flow for threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I haven't done much threading in the past. My assumption of how it should work is as follows:

Start n threads

when a thread finishes, start a new thread and kill the existing one. 
Is this proper?

I'm working in python so I intend on having the main method in my thread create a new instance before it dies. I'm not entirely sure this is safe. Any advice?

Comment: what are you trying to do. Explain what you mean by "Safe"

Comment: and by the way, there is no "main method" in Python.. `__main__` file yes.

Comment: what thread are you going to kill? The one that is finished is dead already. The proper way is to start a thread when doing a parallel job is required, and let the thread finish when the job is done. Do not kill threads - instead, program them so that they know when to die.

Answer (score 2):

A good start would to be to look into the [Producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). It involves two different functions manipulating a single fixed size queue. There are of course multiple solutions to this question but a common way to handle this is with semaphores and mutexs, which are just binary semaphores, which essentially lock and unlock the critical sections, i.e. the functions that manipulate the queue. With this in mind as an example, you would create n number of threads for each function you have, a producer function and consumer function in this example. Then within the producer function you would have a putItem() call surrounded by a mutex lock/unlock that only lets one process run between the mutex calls which is then surrounded by a semaphore that unlocks when the queue is empty and locks when the queue is full. Within the consumer function you would have a getItem() call surrounded by a mutex lock surrounded by a semaphore that unlocks when the queue is full and locks when the queue is empty. I would suggest looking over the wikipedia page and even possibly over [POSIX pthreads](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/l-posix1.xml) its in C but the concepts are there. Then when your ready apply what you've learned in Python and check out their documentation for threading.